# CSS: Why does the style tags need to be included in the html with Pure CSS framework?

Tags: html, css, yui, css-frameworks, yui-pure-css

Why do the style tags need to be included in the HTML with Pure CSS framework?  The documentation has it too http://purecss.io/buttons/ I'm looking at the section "Colored buttons with rounded corners: Success Button"

(look in this [Codepen](http://cdpn.io/wtzbu)  - in bottom left click on edit pen)

notice is you uncomment the style tags in html it works? why can't it pick it up from the css file?

```
<style scoped>

    .button-success,
    .button-error,
    .button-warning,
    .button-secondary {
        color: white;
        border-radius: 4px;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    }

    .button-success {
        background: rgb(28, 184, 65); /* this is a green */
    }

    .button-error {
        background: rgb(202, 60, 60); /* this is a maroon */
    }

    .button-warning {
        background: rgb(223, 117, 20); /* this is an orange */
    }

    .button-secondary {
        background: rgb(66, 184, 221); /* this is a light blue */
    }

</style>

<div>
    <button class="button-success pure-button">Success Button</button>
    <button class="button-error pure-button">Error Button</button>
    <button class="button-warning pure-button">Warning Button</button>
    <button class="button-secondary pure-button">Secondary Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS rules** are assigned based on the **order** in which they are loaded.  You put the Yahoo Pure CSS file loading **inside the `<body>`** of that CodePen but the CSS you have typed in the **CSS section is loaded before it** (in the `<head>`).  This lets the later one **overwrite** it, *reverting* the settings to their defaults.

### Just load the pure file before the other files (but after fonts of course).

Comment: now i understand the rules. but i do not understand how i would do :Just load the pure file before the other files (but after fonts of course).

Comment: `<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.3.0/pure-min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="custom-styles.css"></head>`